# How to install a specific git branch with pipenv

Tags: python, git, pipenv

How can I install a specific git branch with pipenv? I know this command will install the bitcoinlib master branch

```
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib.git#egg=bitcoinlib
```

But how can I install a branch that isn't master?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to simply use the @ symbol to specify branch and change the egg name to be a bit different if you're also using the master or some other branch. Follow this syntax

```
pipenv install -e git+<your/target/git/repository/url.git>@branch#egg=package_name
```

So in my example I needed to use the segwit-support branch

```
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib.git@segwit-support#egg=bitcoinlib_segwitsupport
```

Which adds this line to my pipfile

```
bitcoinlib_segwit-support = {editable = true, ref = "segwit-support", git = "https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib.git"}
```

Comment: Docs for this: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#a-note-about-vcs-dependencies

Comment: "Docs" point to 404

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Post](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2685) discusses exactly your issue. For a specific version/branch you need to modify the https url.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can do that:

- Add in your Pipfile [packages] section

> packages_name  = {git = "https://repository_url.git", ref =
> "branch_name", editable=True}

`editable = True` means that the package is installed in "editable mode." This allows changes made directly to the source code of the package to be immediately reflected in the environment where the package is installed, without needing to reinstall the package.

Example:

[packages]

> nemoguardrails = {git =
> "https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo-Guardrails.git", ref = "develop",
> editable = true}

Once you have done this, run the following in your terminal:

```bash
pipenv install
```